# Is this (tricky) natural deduction with De Morgan's laws correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Just a practice question, however just wondering if this natural deduction  proof is correct?
I have put brackets in 2.2 and not in 2.3 however this shouldn't make a difference?

[image]

Comment: It is not a duplicate, i'm asking is doing it this way a correct way to do it?

Comment: **NO**, it is not; subproof 3 : $\lnot (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \vdash \lnot (P \land Q)$ is *invalid*.

Comment: that's from the data so sub proof 3 I'm 100% sure it is right?

Comment: @user3135672 It's wrong. Correct would be $\lnot (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \vdash P \land Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it's valid. $\lnot (P \land Q)$ is from 1 itself. OP is not using De Morgan's laws.

Comment: @GitGud see above

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong because the application of the rule $\lnot_E$ at step 2.4 is not correct.

I assume that the schema of the rule $\lnot_E$ is the following:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\lnot A \to B \quad \lnot A \to \lnot B}{A}
\end{equation}
(this is the way you have applied it at step 4). This schema is one of the possible formalizations of the classical law known as *reductio ad absurdum*.

At step 2.2 you have proved that $(\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \to \lnot(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$. At step 2.3 you have proved that $(\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \to (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$. But you cannot apply $\lnot_E$ at step 2.4 because $\lnot P \land \lnot Q$ is not a formula of the shape $\lnot A$.

Actually, at step 2.4 you can apply $\lnot_I$ and derive $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$, but this allow you at step 2 to conclude only that $\lnot (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \to \lnot(P \land Q)$ (the same as you have proved at step 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
1. ¬(P∧Q)          [premise]
2.1. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)      [assumption]
2.2.1. ¬P          [assumption]
2.2.2. ¬P∨¬Q       [∨intro 2.2.1]
2.2. ¬P→(¬P∨¬Q)    [→intro 2.2.1-2.2.2]
2.3.1. ¬P          [assumption]
2.3.2. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)    [restate 2.1]
2.3. ¬P→¬(¬P∨¬Q)   [→intro 2.3.1-2.3.2]
2.4. P             [RAA 2.2 2.3]
2.5.1. ¬Q          [assumption]
2.5.2. ¬P∨¬Q       [∨intro 2.5.1]
2.5. ¬Q→(¬P∨¬Q)    [→intro 2.5.1-2.5.2]
2.6.1. ¬Q          [assumption]
2.6.2. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)    [restate 2.1]
2.6. ¬Q→¬(¬P∨¬Q)   [→intro 2.6.1-2.6.2]
2.7. Q             [RAA 2.5 2.6]
2.8. P∧Q           [∧intro 2.4 2.7]
2. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)→(P∧Q)  [→intro 2.1-2.8]
3.1. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)      [assumption]
3.2. ¬(P∧Q)        [restate 1]
3. ¬(¬P∨¬Q)→¬(P∧Q) [→intro 2.1-2.8]
4. ¬P∨¬Q           [RAA 2 3]
```